# I want to print the value excluding the null value. What should I do?

Tags: sql, mariadb

I would like to print out the items shown in the following results.(Excluding null values)
How should the query statement be modified?

My Queries

```
SELECT id, chart_num, chart_name, MIN(DATE) AS DATE, amount, (COUNT(*) = 2) AS result
FROM ((
SELECT id, hpd.chart_num AS chart_num,  hpd.chart_name AS chart_name, hpd.visit AS DATE, card_amount_received AS amount, row_number() over (PARTITION BY card_amount_received ORDER BY id) AS seqnum FROM hospital_payment_data hpd WHERE store_mbrno = '100012')
UNION all
(
SELECT id,  ncd.chart_num  AS chart_num, ncd.chart_name AS chart_name, ncd.date, amount, row_number() over (PARTITION BY amount ORDER BY id) AS seqnum FROM noti_card_data ncd WHERE mbrNo = '100012' AND cmd ='승인')
) X
GROUP BY amount, seqnum
```

my result
[image]

***This is solved it***

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT id, chart_num , chart_name, MIN(DATE) AS DATE, amount, (COUNT(*) = 2) AS result

FROM (

(SELECT id, hpd.chart_num AS chart_num,  hpd.chart_name AS chart_name, hpd.visit AS DATE, card_amount_received AS amount, 
row_number() over (PARTITION BY card_amount_received ORDER BY id) AS seqnum FROM hospital_payment_data hpd WHERE store_mbrno = '100012' )
UNION ALL
(SELECT id,  ncd.chart_num  AS chart_num, ncd.chart_name AS chart_name, ncd.date, amount, 
row_number() over (PARTITION BY amount ORDER BY id) AS seqnum FROM noti_card_data ncd WHERE mbrNo = '100012' AND cmd ='success')

) X  GROUP BY amount, seqnum 
) REX WHERE REX.chart_num IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```sql
WHERE 
chart_name IS NOT NULL AND chart_num IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Where should I put it?